# Map a property to a collection item

Tags: c#, automapper

I've been sifting through AutoMapper documentation to try and find a recommended solution to this but haven't been able to find it.

Let's say I have a class like the following

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

this class gets populated from the client and gets mapped to the following domain object class

```
public class Bar
{
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

where Note is

```
public class Note
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    // other properties excluded for brevity
}
```

I'd like to map the `Note` string property on `Foo`, firstly to the `Text` property on a new instance of `Note` and then add that `Note` to the `Notes` collection on `Bar`. I'm using a `ValueResolver` to perform the first part of this operation (mapping the string to a new instance of `Note`) but am not sure about how to go about the second part (mapping that item to a item in a collection).

What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this should work (not tested -- just typing out loud):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ForMember(d => d.Notes,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(s => new List<Note> { new Note { Text = s.Note } });
```

**EDIT**

You could also use AutoMappers `AfterMap` functionality.  This lambda would be executed after Automapper has done it's regular mappings:

```
.AfterMap((s,d) => d.Notes.Add(new Note { Text = s.Note }));
```

Comment: Bar is a domain object populated from a datasource. I think this will take care of mapping to a new domain object instance, but will it handle the case where the domain object is populated from the datasource and may already contain items in the collection and I would want to add an item to that collection?

Comment: Edited my answer with an option for using AfterMap.  Alternatively, you could use a custom type converter if things get too tricky: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters

Comment: The MapAfter worked a treat, many thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)