# AutoMapper doesn't map ViewModel to Model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model, viewmodel, automapper

I have ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public Developer Developer { get; set; }
        public Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
    }
```

and Model:

```
public class Developer 
        {
            //some stuff
        }
```

I'm trying to map it in the Action:

```
public ActionResult AddDeveloper(EmployeeViewModel employee)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeViewModel, Developer>();
            Developer developer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EmployeeViewModel, Developer>(employee);
            .......
        }
```

after that `developer` variable has no values for parameters that `employee` has. Could you please help me?

Comment: Why not just call employee.Developer?

Comment: You can also make a call to Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() after you create your map. There may be something invalid about your mapping that needs to be customized

Comment: We really could do with seeing 'the stuff', and whilst your at it, add the full definitions for all the types.

Comment: *variable has no values for parameters*? What *exactly* do you mean? A variable doesn't have parameters. This sounds like you should also have mappings for types embedded in the `Developer` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply trying to map a class to a property effectively. You need to explicitly tell how to bring both element onto the same level, for example:

```
public ActionResult AddDeveloper(EmployeeViewModel employee)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeViewModel, Developer>()
                      .ForMember(destination => destination, option => option.MapFrom(source => source.Developer));
            Developer developer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EmployeeViewModel, Developer>(employee);
        }
```

Now the same thing should work. I have never tried doing the mapping at that level, I suspect you may have to try using the "AfterMap" function like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4750709/3002953.