# automapper mapping a indexer

Tags: automapper, indexer

I am trying to write a mapping to map between two classes using automapper.  Most of it is pretty straight forward, direct mappings between 2 fields of the same type.  However, I have an indexer on each class that may that need to map to each other.  It probably isn't relevant that the source type has an indexer, so essentially what I am trying to do is something like:

```
mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d["Text"], opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Text));
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: I think [using AfterMap][1] would be the best place for something like this.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733410/automapper-map-a-property-to-a-collection-item/4750709#4750709