# Mapping string to List<string> and vice versa using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Basically I have this class which represents 1:1 with my database

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this viewmodel

```
public class UserEditViewModel
{
    public UserEditViewModel()
    {
        Roles = new List<string>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to map between these 2. My current setup :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserEditViewModel, User>().ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is something similar to your questiong here, please can you check this out [AutoMapper: Collection to Single string Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816068/automapper-collection-to-single-string-property)

PS: This is an example for mapping collection to single string property probably your example should look like below;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserEditViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles,
    m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Role.Split(',').ToList()));
```

And mapping the instances like below;

```
User myUser = new User();
myUser.Role = "r1,r2,r3,r4,r5";
myUser.UserID = 1;
myUser.Username = "MyUserName";

UserEditViewModel result = Mapper.Map<UserEditViewModel>(myUser);
```

[image]

2020 Edit: Since `Expression.Call` API does not support optional parameter and you should Replace `src.Role.Split(',')` with `src.Role.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.None)` or `src.Role.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Is it still possible to use `ReverseMap` or do we need to do the opposite the other way?

Comment: It would be great if this worked, but I get `CS0854  An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments` on the `Split` call.

Comment: Hey @DavidDombrowsky , since `options` parameter of Split is optional and `Expression.Call` api does not support method calls with optional parameter you need to provide it yourself or you may create you own method which wraps Split. This is required because of the AutoMapper's changes.

Comment: Thank you @CihanUygun.  Wrapping it in a static function that does the same thing without optional params seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

To map a string to a collection **Cihan Uygun's** answer works, only to fix the error

> CS0854  An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that
> uses optional arguments

which is caused in later updates you should Replace `src.Role.Split(',')` with `src.Role.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.None)` or `src.Role.Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

To do the **reverse mapping** just use `src =>  string.Join(',', src.Roles)`

Source for the error fix: https://newbedev.com/mapping-string-to-list-string-and-vice-versa-using-automapper

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate all values in your list of string you need to use `string.Join`. In mapper you need to use `ForMember` method.

From `UserEditViewModel` to `User`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserEditViewModel>().ForMember(user => user.Role, opt => opt.MapFrom(userEdit => string.Join(", ", userEdit.Roles)));
```

From `User` to `UserEditViewModel`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserEditViewModel, User>().ForMember(userEdit => userEdit.Roles, opt => opt.MapFrom(user => user.Role.Split(",").ToList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the AutoMapper AfterMap, something like this:

```
.AfterMap((src,dest) => dest.Roles.Add(src.Role))
```

Credit to the answer here: [Map a property to a collection item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733410/automapper-map-a-property-to-a-collection-item)