# Automapper mapping string to List<string>

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, automapper

I have two classes

```
 public class SourceClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
}


public class DestinationClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Provider { get; set; }
}
```

I've initialized my mapping by using the following code

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
```

And then in my controller, I have :

```
Mapper.Map<List<DestinationClass>>(requests)
```

where "requests" is a List of SourceClass objects being passed in to my controller.

**My question is, how can I map the Provider(of type string) in my SourceClass to Provider(of type  List in my Destination class?**

The provider in sourceclass will always be a single string, and provider in the destination class will always be a list of a single string.

Here is what I've tried in the mapping configurations:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => {
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Provider) ? [""] : src.Provider.ToList());
```

Comment: Can you describe in English how the string maps to a list of strings?  Does it become a list containing that single string?

Comment: @Amy correct, so if the string in my source class was "Test", it should be ["Test"] in my destination class.

Comment: What issue are you running into exactly?

Comment: @TylerHundley I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this, so I've tried using .ForMember and the ternary operator but not able to understand why it isn't working.

Comment: If the string is null or empty, its an empty list?  Or is it a null list?  Or does the list contain the empty string?

Comment: See my answer below. I don't think you were far off. I think using the making a new list and using the [null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operators is your best/cleanest bet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping string to List<string> and vice versa using Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008760/mapping-string-to-liststring-and-vice-versa-using-automapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I'd recommend renaming your destination property to `Providers` to avoid confusion/represent that it is a collection. Then you could give this a try

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Providers,
  memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => new List<string> {src.Provider ?? ""}));
```

Specifically this bit

```
src => new List<string> {src.Provider ?? ""}
```

Creates a new list of type string with one value, either `src.Provider`, or if that is null, an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your mapping configuration with this one:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
  .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
  memberOptions => memberOptions
    .MapFrom(src => 
    { 
      return new List<string>{ string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Provider) ? "" : src.Provider)
    });
```

Comment: Multiple lines of code should be formatted using triple backticks or by prefixing each line with four spaces.  Single backticks are for inline code.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your source member's Provider property to a List, you would get a List of char type. 
This code should reflect what you need.

```cs
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
.ForMember(
    destinationMember => destinationMember.Provider,
    memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(
        src => string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Provider) ? new List<string>() { "" } : new List<string> { src.Provider }
    )
);
```